# How to randomize database attribute without duplication

Tags: mysql, vb.net, xampp

The questions did random but it sometimes and most likely duplicate or occur again together with the choices on the next question. I think the Order By Rand() is causing it or I lack on something.

```
Dim n As Integer = 0
    Dim Qid As String = ""
    Dim numItems As Integer

     Private Sub QuestionNavigation()
            rdbA.Checked = False
            rdbB.Checked = False
            rdbC.Checked = False
            rdbD.Checked = False

            Dim qDT As DataTable = DTTable("SELECT *", "tblQuestions ORDER by Rand()", "")

            numItems = qDT.Rows.Count
            If (numItems > 0) Then
                If (n < numItems) Then
                    lblQuestionNumber.Text = "Question {" & (n + 1) & "} of {" & qDT.Rows.Count & "}"
                    Qid = qDT.Rows(n).Item(0).ToString()
                    txtQuestion.Text = qDT.Rows(n).Item(1).ToString()

                    Dim qcDT As DataTable = DTTable("SELECT *", "tblChoices", " WHERE QuestionID='" & Qid & "'")
                    txtChoiceA.Text = qcDT.Rows(0).Item(2).ToString()
                    txtChoiceB.Text = qcDT.Rows(1).Item(2).ToString()
                    txtChoiceC.Text = qcDT.Rows(2).Item(2).ToString()
                    txtChoiceD.Text = qcDT.Rows(3).Item(2).ToString()
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Congratulation! You have completed the exam. Thank you for your cooperation.", "Complete", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
                    Close()
                    DisplayForm(frmLogin, frmMain.pnlMain)
                End If
            End If
        End Sub
```

tblQuestions

```
 QuestionID Question
    Q170001 A _________ is a group of sentence about one topic. 
    Q170002 It is a natural process of recieving aural and visual stimuli.  
    Q170003 A specific place to show where the departure and arrival gates from other country is seen.  
    Q170004 The term communication was derived from the term _________. 
    Q170005 Human behavior states that the lowest IQ level of a person is ________? 
    Q170006 These are the most prominent and cognitive functions distinguishing human being to animals. 
    Q170007 The price of these jeans _____ reasonable.  
    Q170008 What as the most important tool that they used to reach the tiny whaling station of Stromness?  0
    Q170009 The _______, _______, ________, _______ balloons add joy to the family. 0
    Q170010 An electronic device system designed to manipulate data.    
    Q170011 The first commercial version of he internet was launched in year
    Q170012 The _________, the first form of todays Internet, was successfully launched in 1969.
    Q170013 The Internet entered the Philippines in 1994, through he initiative of the
    Q170014 Computer Engineer ________ is the guy to than for the electronic mail that had simplified todays communication. 
    Q170015 Email was message was   
    Q170016 The _____ symbol chose to tell which user was "at" which computer   
    Q170017 A _______________ is a technology that allows one to make telephone call using a high speed internet connection instead of using
    an analog phone line.   
    Q170018 A ___________ is a device that converts analog signal from the public telephone network (PIN) info digital signals inside your computer anf vice-versa.
```

How can I apply array with this if needed? I have currently 18 questions on the list

Comment: How can I create an index to maintain the current one? sorry I'm still new in VB

Comment: Your `n` variable is probably trying to do that but it is hard to tell.  The main thing is that you want to randomize the order once per quiz

Comment: Maybe I should use array with the number of question items? But don't know how and where to insert it.

Comment: If you want to code it in baby steps where you get them one by one, get all the Ids into something in random order.  Then use an index var (`Private CurrentQuestion As Integer = 0`).  That points to the next question ID.  Use that to look up the Q and Choices (although using a JOIN you get get both all at once).  To go to the next one, just increment `CurrentQuestion` to point to the next one

Comment: How and where should be the code look like?